# html react parser throws an issue

Tags: reactjs, html-react-parser

I am trying to render html content via `html-react-parser` in react. But I will get following error in the console.

`Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <html> cannot appear as a child of <div>.`

My html input to the parse method is as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   body {
     background-color: lightblue;
   }

   h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
   }

   p {
     font-family: verdana;
     font-size: 20px;
   }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

 <h1>My First CSS Example</h1>
 <p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

So I know the reason for the issue was my inner html contains inside of html tag. But I don't need to remove it because that input is coming from backend and I need to render as it is via the parser. Is there any way get rid from this console log error?

Comment: To clarify, this isn't an error, this is just a warning. with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` this should not be logged. but just for that, imo it's not worth to set this option.

Comment: yes, since `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` not applying css it's not worth to use in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert `html` as a child of `div` that's why you get this.
Try using only the code you need:

```
<h1>My First CSS Example</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: I need to apply internal css as well